# I have separate, finished pieces. How to assemble them?

Tags: furniture, assembly

This question is woodworking-related. Recently, I found in the attic (in France) the wood pieces shown on this photo. There are:

- 1 round, flat, 40-cm diameter disc, with a hand-carved, 5mm-deep grooove all around
- 3 identical long, twisted, holed pieces with a ring at one extremity.

I have the intuition that all those are part of a small table. However, I cannot find a way to put them together. I may be missing a piece of the puzzle.

Any idea?

[image: the puzzling wood pieces]

Comment: Is the back of the disc any different from the side we are seeing?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. This looks like a craftsman-made item (possibly Asian but this is merely a guess based on the wood which looks like it might be a tropical hardwood) so unfortunately there's a chance nobody will have seen anything quite like it before. Since there are three legs with a hole in the centre a type of interlocking tripod was the first thing that came to my mind, however I can't figure out how they'd fit together and I presume that's one of the arrangements you'll have already thought of yourself and tried. [contd]

Comment: Of course there's the chance that this isn't all of it, that you're missing one or more parts. And the loop with the ring in it suggests the possibility of lashings or maybe rope as part of the assembly.

Comment: @ThatCoolCoder The other side is completely flat.

Comment: @Graphus You are right: I tried placing the "legs" into the others, but nothing is satisfying.

Comment: Isn't the goal of these 3D puzzles to solve them yourself? ;)

Comment: I found a picture of something similar: [https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/2yEAAOSwmFhbq9~M/s-l400.jpg](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/2yEAAOSwmFhbq9~M/s-l400.jpg)

Comment: @ThatCoolCoder, what a great find! That's exactly the kind of interlock I was thinking might be possible but I couldn't get my head around it in the abstract. From the one photo it does seem it would be how these legs go together, with one 'slot' appearing to be longer than the other two.

Comment: On the tabletop you can see the worn spots where the 3 legs would go. The legs show one end narrower than the other. They would fit into the groove. Invite some friends over and play a game of "Reverse Jenga" trying to place the legs. Have fun.

Comment: For What it's Worth: I remember [seeing this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vd2P0PeXB8) and thought of it reading here.... (it's a youtube video of someome experimenting with a similar structure, so you may/may not want to click it)

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that each of the upper two pieces has a carved leaf on the other side of the right-hand part? If so, the leaf probably indicated the "outside" of the assembled tripod.

Comment: My guess would bee that the two upper "legs" are criss-crossed, then inserted into the larger opening in the lower "leg". I'd also guess that either the right-hand ends of the legs snap into the slot in the disk (and this may account for what looks like extra carving on the inside of the slot), with tension on the legs being what holds the assembly together (which means it will be a nerve-wrackingly tight fit to assemble) or there is a missing wedge piece which goes in one of the openings.